# cakephp 1.3 paginating habtm related data

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have searched high and low and tried multiple different solutions to this and I cannot seem to get it to work.
Basically I have products and categories.
Categories has and belongs to many products, and products HABTM categories. They are obviously related in a join table products_categories with id,product_id,category_id fields.

After a simple full bake- models views and controllers are baked - some categories and products are added and their relationships are set I can go to a specific category view page and the pre baked view will show products that are related to this category.

However, there is quite a few products (and will be more) and I am struggling to work out how to paginate all of this related data..as it is unfeasible to just simply list all of the products in a category (there could be 100s or more)
Can anybody help? It seems there are quite a few unanswered topics on this and various different solutions, none of which I can get to work! Please help!

Comment: Not related to your problem, to be sure, but CakePHP convention indicates that your `products_categories` table should be named `categories_products`

Comment: I don't understand? It is named products_categories and seems to work fine..what difference would naming the table the other way make?

Comment: In the documentation "Join tables, used in hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) relationships between models should be named after the model tables they will join in alphabetical order (apples_zebras rather than zebras_apples)." http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions  Doing it this way will let cake apply more of it's "Magic" and keep you from having boilerplate code in the model telling it what table to use.

Comment: ah thank you! should I rename my models then? Products_category to Categories_product. Having asked that, is there a use in having a Categories_product (orwhatever) model/controller or is it unecessary? (it was simply baked in the bake all script) Thank you!

Comment: Wait..  you have created a ProductsCategory model?  You should just delete it.  Cake generates HABTM models for your join tables on the fly when you run your application.  As long as you rename the table to `categories_products`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP controllers have [built in pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1231/Pagination).  The documentation is thorough, so I would recommend reading that first.  Afterwards, I'd be happy to answer any questions you have on the subject.

Without knowing the specific code involved, here is a simple example of how to paginate your model data:

```
class CategoryController extends AppController {
    var $paginate = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'categories_products', // or products_categories
                    'alias' => 'CatFilter',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'CatFilter.product_id = Product.id'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'limit' => 10
         )
    );

    function view ($category_id) {
        $this->set(
            'products', $this->paginate(
                $this->Category->Product, array(
                    'CatFilter.category_id' => $category_id
                )
             )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have read the pagination section, and I can not find anything that relates to my issue. I will re-read, but is there something inparticular that I am missing here? thanks

Comment: Ooops.  Fixed an erroneous section.  If you already tried my method and it failed, try it now.

Comment: This works! excellent! however, small issue, the 'next' page is unclickable, it goes from /categories/view/1/ to categories/view/page:2

Comment: cancel that, that was due to some redundant code I hade in (it was pasted) from another views file. Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!  BTW:  Using a filtering table join like this has allowed me to do lots of great things in CakePHP.  You should read up on those joins and try to follow exactly what I've done here, because you'll inevitably use it again.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this article http://blog.sohaibmuneer.com/using-mysql-inner-join-in-cakephp-pagination
and also you can use join in your find query http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1047/Joining-tables